# Issue with python module importing

Tags: python, instance, python-import, python-module

In dir tree looks like this

PyPong
 + Main.py
 + Rectangle.py

Now, I have imported Rectangle.py like this in Main.py

```
import pygame, sys, Rectangle
```

However, whenever I try making an instance of the class Rectangle.py like here

```
rectangles.append(Rectangle(400 + x * rectangleWidth + x * 10, 30 + y * rectangleHeight + y * 10, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight, (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)), screen))
```

into this array

```
rectangles = []
```

I recieve this error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Also, here is the full Rectangle.py

```
class Rectangle:

    y = 0
    x = 0
    width = 0
    height = 0
    color = 0
    screen = 0

    GO_UP = 1
    GO_DOWN = 2
    GO_LEFT = 3
    GO_RIGHT = 4

    closeX = 0
    closeY = 0

    removed = False

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color, screen):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.screen = screen

    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)
        pass

    def intersects(self, x, y, r):
        #TOP SIDE
        self.closeX = 0
        self.closeY = 0
        intersectsTop = True;
        if x <= self.x: self.closeX = self.x
        elif x >= self.x + self.width: self.closeX = self.x + self.width
        else: self.closeX = self.x
        self.closeY = self.y
        if abs(x - self.closeX) >= r: intersectsTop = False
        if abs(y - self.closeY) >= r: intersectsTop = False
        if intersectsTop: 
            self.remove()
            return self.GO_UP

        #LEFT SIDE
        self.closeX = 0
        self.closeY = 0
        intersectsLeft = True
        if y <= self.y: self.closeY = self.y
        elif y >= self.y + self.height: self.closeY = self.y + self.height
        else: self.closeY = y;
        self.closeX = self.x
        if abs(x - self.closeX) >= r: intersectsLeft = False
        if abs(y - self.closeY) >= r: intersectsLeft = False
        if intersectsLeft: 
            self.remove()
            return self.GO_LEFT

        #RIGHT SIDE
        self.closeX = 0
        self.closeY = 0
        intersectsRight = True
        if y <= self.y: self.closeY = self.y
        elif y >= self.y + self.height: self.closeY = self.y + self.height
        else: self.closeY = y;
        self.closeX = self.x + self.width
        if abs(x - self.closeX) >= r: intersectsRight = False
        if abs(y - self.closeY) >= r: intersectsRight = False
        if intersectsRight: 
            self.remove()
            return self.GO_RIGHT

        #BOTTOM SIDE
        self.closeX = 0
        self.closeY = 0
        intersectsBottom = True;
        if x <= self.x: self.closeX = self.x
        elif x >= self.x + self.width: self.closeX = self.x + self.width
        else: self.closeX = self.x
        self.closeY = self.y + self.height
        if abs(x - self.closeX) >= r: intersectsBottom = False
        if abs(y - self.closeY) >= r: intersectsBottom = False
        if intersectsBottom: 
            self.remove()
            return self.GO_DOWN
        pass

    def remove(self):
        self.removed = True
        pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the class from the module:

```
from Rectangle import Rectangle
```

or refer to the class as an attribute of the module you imported:

```
rectangles.append(Rectangle.Rectangle(400 + x * rectangleWidth + x * 10, 30 + y * rectangleHeight + y * 10, rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight, (randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)), screen))
```

This is one reason for the [Python style guide PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names) to recommend that you use all-lowercase names for your module files, to avoid confusing the module with the contents of the module.

Answer (score 0):

You imported the `Rectangle` module, but not the `Rectangle` class within the Rectangle module.

To reference classes within a module, the general syntax is `module.Class`.  So you can change your references to `Rectangle.Rectangle` or instead import the class directly:

```
from Rectangle import Rectangle
```